# Get min date in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

How do I get the min date of a timestamp field?

I tried to use

```
select min(myDatefield) from mytable
```

but this code doesn't returns the minimum date, but all dates.
Any clue why?

Comment: Please provide sample data, current output and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this might work for you.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT MCSSP_AUDIT_ACTIVITY_DATE
  FROM MCSSP_MESG_AUDIT_BK
  ORDER BY MCSSP_AUDIT_ACTIVITY_DATE ASC
  )
WHERE rownum = 1;
```